# Calculate confidence intervals for multiple samples in R

Tags: r, function, matrix

This question is for the confidence interval for multiple samples using R-statistical package.

I created a matrix normsample=matrix(rnorm(25*100, man-6, sd=3), 25, 100). Also I have this function:

```
>  CIfun <- function(x, alpha, x.var)
>     {
>         ## Computes a confidence interval for mu from X ~ N(mu, x.var)
>         ## x is a vector containing observations from X
>         ## 1-alpha is the desired confidence level
>         ## x.var is the assumed known variance for X
>         n <- length(x)                 # find the number of elements in x
>         x.mean <- mean(x)              # calculate the mean of x
>         z <- qnorm(1-alpha/2)          # appropriate z-value
>         lo <- x.mean - z*sqrt(x.var/n) # lower bound
>         hi <- x.mean + z*sqrt(x.var/n) # upper bound
>         return(c(lo, hi))              # return confidence interval as a vector
>     }
```

Now I am asked to use the "apply" function and CIfun to create a 2x100 matrix with the name meanconf. The ith column should contain the 90% confidence interval for μ for the ith sample of size 25 with lower bounds on the first row and the upper bounds on the second row. I can understand what they ask me to do but I do not know how to create this matrix. Any ideas?
(I use my CIfun and apply function but I obtain the value of the confidence interval for the whole matrix (as x is a matrix ). But I want to calculate the confidence interval for each entry of the matrix)

Comment: Try `apply(normsample,2,CIfun, alpha, x.var)`

Comment: Do you want to calculate the average from multiple `matrices`

Comment: I used apply(normsample,2,CIfun,alpha x.var) as you suggested and it works!!

Comment: Therefore I have a function "meanconf <- apply(normsample,2,CIfun, 0.1, 9)".  Now I am asked to say what R command I used to create meanconf, what does this mean?

Comment: It seems to me that you wanted to create a list of matrices and get the mean of those values returned by CIfun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps:

```
Reduce(`+`,lapply(lst, function(x) #apply CIfun over individual list elements  
         apply(x, 2, CIfun, 0.10, 9)))/length(lst) 
                                   #get the mean
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)                      #set a seed
lst <- lapply(1:10, function(i)   #crete a list of matrices
      matrix(rnorm(25*100, mean=6, sd=3), 25, 100))
```